# Regarding Running Munit for Mule Flow

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-esb

I am facing the below issue while running in Munit , I tried changing the workspace , installed plugins , but munit nothing seems to be working .The error of the screenshot is attached .Click on the blue link below to see the screenshot .

Thanks

[Error while running Munit for flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr4Ud.png)

Comment: Hello welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post screenshots. Rather, copy and paste your error message preferably using the code formatting tools. This will make it much more likely that someone will address your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error while  running munit. The solution for that issue  is you need open the using run as administrator option.

Comment: I am having community edition . I don't see any option to run flow as administrator comes .Please let me know in Anypoint Studio  where I can get it .

Comment: You have to run the studio using administrator not the flow.

Answer (score 0):

close the studio and stop the process javaw.exe from task manager and try once.